# Syntaxnet all Bazel Tests Failed

Tags: macos, testing, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I've followed the instructions for installing syntaxnet manually on the github page https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet and I made it all the way to building and testing SyntaxNet

When I try to run the bazel test command on my mac I get a ton of warnings during compilation, all of which seem to resolve themselves until I get to here:

```
INFO: From Linking external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/libgather_functor.lo:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-opt/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/libgather_functor.lo(gather_functor.o) has no symbols
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-opt/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/libgather_functor.lo the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_jcowell/fd6f80e8a4b7414861a87a91e847bf41/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:476:1: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:array_ops_op_lib' failed (Exit 1).
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:181:9: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
        return errors::InvalidArgument("shape attr must be fully defined.");
        ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:189:11: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
          return errors::InvalidArgument(
          ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:194:11: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
          return errors::InvalidArgument("Size of first dimension must be 1.");
          ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:196:9: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
        TF_RETURN_WITH_CONTEXT_IF_ERROR(c->Merge(c->input(i), cur, &cur),
        ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/lib/core/errors.h:51:7: note: expanded from macro 'TF_RETURN_WITH_CONTEXT_IF_ERROR'
      return _status;                                               \
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:203:7: error: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:173:17: error: no viable conversion from 'tensorflow::(lambda at external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:173:17)' to 'tensorflow::Status (*)(shape_inference::InferenceContext *)'
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:173:17: note: candidate function
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:247:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn' here
      Status (*fn)(shape_inference::InferenceContext*)) {
               ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:254:7: error: return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type '::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(GetAxisForPackAndUnpack(c, rank + 1, &axis));
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/lib/core/errors.h:43:42: note: expanded from macro 'TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR'
    if (TF_PREDICT_FALSE(!_status.ok())) return _status; \
                                         ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:329:7: error: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:303:17: error: no viable conversion from 'tensorflow::(lambda at external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:303:17)' to 'tensorflow::Status (*)(shape_inference::InferenceContext *)'
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:303:17: note: candidate function
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:247:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn' here
      Status (*fn)(shape_inference::InferenceContext*)) {
               ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:451:9: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
        TF_RETURN_WITH_CONTEXT_IF_ERROR(
        ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/lib/core/errors.h:51:7: note: expanded from macro 'TF_RETURN_WITH_CONTEXT_IF_ERROR'
      return _status;                                               \
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:459:7: error: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:435:17: error: no viable conversion from 'tensorflow::(lambda at external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:435:17)' to 'tensorflow::Status (*)(shape_inference::InferenceContext *)'
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:435:17: note: candidate function
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:247:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn' here
      Status (*fn)(shape_inference::InferenceContext*)) {
               ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:498:9: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
        return errors::InvalidArgument("Can't split scalars");
        ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:518:11: error: return type '::tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
          return errors::InvalidArgument(
          ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:529:7: error: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:482:17: error: no viable conversion from 'tensorflow::(lambda at external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:482:17)' to 'tensorflow::Status (*)(shape_inference::InferenceContext *)'
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:482:17: note: candidate function
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:247:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn' here
      Status (*fn)(shape_inference::InferenceContext*)) {
               ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:560:7: error: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:550:17: error: no viable conversion from 'tensorflow::(lambda at external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:550:17)' to 'tensorflow::Status (*)(shape_inference::InferenceContext *)'
    .SetShapeFn([](InferenceContext* c) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:550:17: note: candidate function
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:247:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'fn' here
      Status (*fn)(shape_inference::InferenceContext*)) {
               ^
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc:585:7: error: return type 'tensorflow::Status' must match previous return type 'const ::tensorflow::Status' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
      return Status::OK();
      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
INFO: Elapsed time: 715.003s, Critical Path: 46.48s
//dragnn/components/stateless:stateless_component_test                NO STATUS
//dragnn/components/syntaxnet:syntaxnet_component_test                NO STATUS
//dragnn/components/syntaxnet:syntaxnet_link_feature_extractor_test   NO STATUS
//dragnn/components/syntaxnet:syntaxnet_transition_state_test         NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:beam_test                                               NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:compute_session_impl_test                               NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:compute_session_pool_test                               NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:dragnn_bulk_op_kernels_test                             NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:dragnn_op_kernels_test                                  NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:index_translator_test                                   NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:input_batch_cache_test                                  NO STATUS
//dragnn/core:resource_container_test                                 NO STATUS
//dragnn/io:sentence_input_batch_test                                 NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:bulk_component_test                                   NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:composite_optimizer_test                              NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:digraph_ops_test                                      NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:evaluation_test                                       NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:graph_builder_test                                    NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:lexicon_test                                          NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:network_units_test                                    NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:render_parse_tree_graphviz_test                       NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:render_spec_with_graphviz_test                        NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:sentence_io_test                                      NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:spec_builder_test                                     NO STATUS
//dragnn/python:visualization_test                                    NO STATUS
//dragnn/tools:model_trainer_test                                     NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:arc_standard_transitions_test                             NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:beam_reader_ops_test                                      NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:binary_segment_state_test                                 NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:binary_segment_transitions_test                           NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:char_ngram_string_extractor_test                          NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:char_properties_test                                      NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:char_shift_transitions_test                               NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:graph_builder_test                                        NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:head_transitions_test                                     NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:label_transitions_test                                    NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:lexicon_builder_test                                      NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:morphology_label_set_test                                 NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:once_transitions_test                                     NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:parser_features_test                                      NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:parser_trainer_test                                       NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:reader_ops_test                                           NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:segmenter_utils_test                                      NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:sentence_features_test                                    NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:shared_store_test                                         NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:tagger_transitions_test                                   NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:text_formats_test                                         NO STATUS
//syntaxnet/util:check_test                                           NO STATUS
//syntaxnet/util:registry_test                                        NO STATUS
//syntaxnet:whole_sentence_features_test                              NO STATUS

Executed 0 out of 51 tests: 1 fails to build and 50 were skipped.
```

I also figured I'd include my bazel version for reference

```
110309-cn2133:syntaxnet jcowell$ bazel version
Build label: 0.5.3-homebrew
Build target: bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Sun Aug 6 12:50:34 2017 (1502023834)
Build timestamp: 1502023834
Build timestamp as int: 1502023834
```

Please help I have literally no idea what's going on

Comment: What version of gcc is on your system? (`gcc --verison`)

Comment: `110309-cn2133:syntaxnet jcowell$ gcc --version
Configured with: --
prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have to upgrade your Xcode. Take a look here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/130.